# Why is class version used by boost serialization limited to 8 bits?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost v1.63's XML serialization.

I maintain application version number as a preprocessor macro e.g

`#define APP_INT_VERSION        10101     \\ version 1.1.1`

It would have been good to use `APP_INT_VERSION` as version number for my serialized classes (using boost's macro like:

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(MySerializedClass, APP_INT_VERSION)
```

But it gives a compile time error - pointing me at boost/serialization/version.hpp  => line# 78 reading:

```
// version numbers limited to 8 bits !!!
```

I wonder why this restriction of 8 bits?

Comment: Because the purpose is to be as small as possible ?

Comment: Don’t use the app version as the class version; just bump it when you need to for each class individually.

Comment: @Stargateur isn't this rather too small to be? Aren't software/classes expected to get updated more than 255 times?

Comment: During main development then yes classes could change quite a lot from day to day, but then it's not a problem since if you modify the class in a relevant way, just keep the same version number (for the class) and simply delete any serialized data. Also, there could easily be changes that are backward compatible, like just adding members while keeping the order of existing members, then you don't need to modify the version number as well. The class version number really only need to be modified if there is a non-backward-compatible change made.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Stargateur,
Thanks for the insight. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The version parameter is of type int, so you can use its full range. Just omit the BOOST_CLASS_VERSION macro and set the version by direct template specialization as stated [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html). The assert for version<256 serves in my opinion as a best practice only.

Full sample code follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

#define APP_INT_VERSION        10101    

class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
      using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
      ar & make_nvp("deg", degrees);
      ar & make_nvp("min", minutes);
      ar & make_nvp("sec", seconds);
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

namespace boost {                                                      
namespace serialization {                                              
template<>                                                             
struct version<gps_position>                                                     
{                                                                      
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(int, value = APP_INT_VERSION);          
};                                                                     
}                                                                      
}


int main() {
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(g);

    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, it is not a good idea to increase serialization version so often (as already commented by others).